# What does "with input" mean?

Tags: meaning

> We expect you to do great things with your work here. When that
>   happens is up to you (with input from your manager, of course).

What does "with input from your manager, of course" mean? Does it mean that "of course you have to follow the direction from you manager"?

What's confusing for me is what this "with" exactly means.
Does mean that "there will be input from your manager" or does it mean that "you should use/follow your manager's input"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably means that, but on the surface it is not as specific. It means that the manager will tell you things that you will need to take into account, but this won't necessarily be instructions. For example, it might be suggestions, feedback, or creative ideas.

Comment: Then does this sentence mean that "When that happens is up to you. Of course there will be your manager's suggestions"?

Comment: No. It doesn't mean "with your manager's commands". It doesn't means "with your manager's suggestions". It doesn't mean "with your manager's feedback". It doesn't mean "with your manager hindering you every step of the way". It means any of the above, and more options besides: it is (perhaps deliberately) unspecific.

Comment: Ok. I understood that the meaning of "input" is unspecific. So this sentence means "When that happens is up to you. Of course there will be your manager's input"?

Comment: Yes. I didn't realise what you didn't understand - I thought you were asking about the meaning of "input".